# Chown accident, everything owned by user "bunchy7s"

Tags: chown

Wanted to do `chown -r bunchy7s /var/lib/jellyfin`,
I however forgot the `var/lib/jellyfin` part.

now everything is owned by bunchy7s!  :)
and nothing works how you would expect! Yay!